# Compartilhando variáveis entre funções no controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho uma função no meu controller que recebe alguns requests, e no final tudo é armazenado em dois arrays.
Nesta função, se eu fizer o seguinte:

```
 return view('negocio.detalhes-trajetoa', compact('arrayLogradourosA', 'arrayLogradourosB'));
```

Eu consigo acessar estes dois arrays nesta view.

Mas o meu objetivo é passar estes dois arrays para outra função do meu controller, pra ficar assim:

```
public function outraFuncao () {
    return view('negocio.detalhes-trajetoa', compact('arrayLogradourosA', 'arrayLogradourosB'));
}
```

Mas como estes dois arrays estão em outra função do meu controller, na minha view dá aquele erro "Undefined variable".

Como eu posso compartilhar estes dois arrays para uma outra função no meu controller??

Answer (score 1):

A função [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php) só funciona com variáveis de escopo local.

Para reutilizar essas variáveis é preciso passá-las para o novo método.

```
public function routeEndpoint() {
    // ..

    return $this->outraFuncao($arrayLogradourosA, $arrayLogradourosB);
}

private function outraFuncao ($arrayLogradourosA, $arrayLogradourosB) {
    return view(
        'negocio.detalhes-trajetoa', 
        compact('arrayLogradourosA', 'arrayLogradourosB')
    );
}
```

Pelo que entendi esse segundo método é usado internamente pelos outros *endpoints* de rotas do *controller*. Logo sua visibilidade não precisar ser publica e no exemplo mudei para `private`.

Comment: E ae Santos, beleza? Bacana sua resposta, mas o problema é que a minha primeira função, no seu exemplo, a routeEndpoint() ela já retorna dados para outra view, se eu colocar esse return,ele não funciona. Tem outro jeito de mandar esses dois arrays pra outraFuncao()?

Comment: de um jeito fácil, não. Um método fica dependente do outro.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, você pode definir variáveis globais no seu controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $arrayLogradourosA;
    private $arrayLogradourosB;

    public function funcao1($cidade, $cidade2)
    {
        $this->$arrayLogradourosA = Logradouros::where('cidade', $cidade)->get();
        $this->$arrayLogradourosB = Logradouros::where('cidade', $cidade2)->get();
    }

    private function outraFuncao() { 
        $arrayLogradourosA = $this->arrayLogradourosA;
        $arrayLogradourosB = $this->arrayLogradourosB;

        return view(
            'negocio.detalhes-trajetoa', 
            compact('arrayLogradourosA', 'arrayLogradourosB')
        );
    }
}
```

É um exemplo genérico, pois não entendi ao certo o motivo de não ser tudo em apenas uma função.